# Performance difference between 'with open(file):' and just opening/closing it manually

Tags: python, file, error-handling, with-statement, try-finally

I think everyone will agree that

```
with open(file_name, 'mode') as f:
    #do things with f
```

is way better than

```
f = open(file_name, 'mode')
#do things with f
f.close()
```

From http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm we can read

> When the “with” statement is executed, Python evaluates the expression, calls the **enter** method on the resulting value (which is called a “context guard”), and assigns whatever **enter** returns to the variable given by as. Python will then execute the code body, and no matter what happens in that code, call the guard object’s **exit** method.

In other words, the `with` has a **similar** structure to this

```
def controlled_execution():
    set things up
    try:
        yield thing
    finally:
        tear things down

for thing in controlled_execution():
    do something with thing
```

Knowing that :

> The try-finally construct guarantees that the "finally" part is always executed, even if the code that does the work doesn’t finish.

So, once the file in open, no matter what happens, it will also be closed, saving from the possibility that the file will stay open without us knowing, returning errors like:

> Error: Windows32 |
>   ERROR_SHARING_VIOLATION
>   32 (0x20) |
>   The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

in case of operations on the same file.

I dont want to digress too much, so I'll go straight to the point,
if I have simple code where I know **for sure** the text file will be closed (EDIT: Thanks to answer now I know that ***we can't be sure***)

```
f = open(file_name, 'w')
f.write('something')
f.close()
```

what's the **REAL** difference with

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
    f.write('something')
```

In terms of performance and not safety, isn't better the manual opening/closing? The code is definitely shorter to handle, plus there is not indentation. Can someone explain me why even on safe codes people use `with open(file)`?

Comment: It may not be obvious but, in your example above, you do not know the file will be closed... any exception in the write or close lines would leave the file open and in limbo.  The whole purpose of using a context is to protect your code from very hard to diagnose bugs... Performance is really a non issue unless you are opening millions of files.

Comment: @cstrutton Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's python convention. There's no meaningful performance difference.

Additionally, you *don't* know for sure that the file will always be closed. The `f.write('something')` line can blow up.